# How to resolve Ripple test server connection error?

Tags: javascript, ripple, cryptocurrency

I am persistently getting following error on connecting to test server using RippleAPI for Javascript:

```
[ConnectionError(Error: connect() timed out after 2000 ms. If your internet connection is working, the rippled server may be blocked or inaccessible.)]
```

However, if I try to get balance from curl, it works:

```
curl 'https://testnet.data.api.ripple.com/v2/accounts/rwAVpkGNU9Shn63EpFq7ju1tr89SsSBwHz/balances?currency=XRP'
```

Code snippet below:

```
'use strict';
const RippleAPI = require('ripple-lib').RippleAPI;

const api = new RippleAPI({
  server: 'wss://s.altnet.rippletest.net:51233' // Public rippled server
});
api.connect().then(() => {
  /* begin custom code ------------------------------------ */
  const myAddress = 'rwAVpkGNU9Shn63EpFq7ju1tr89SsSBwHz';

  console.log('getting account info for', myAddress);
  return api.getAccountInfo(myAddress);

}).then(info => {
  console.log(info);
  console.log('getAccountInfo done');

  /* end custom code -------------------------------------- */
}).then(() => {
  return api.disconnect();
}).then(() => {
  console.log('done and disconnected.');
}).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

timeout param doesn't seem to work even if I suggest;

use:
`api.connection._config.connectionTimeout = 3e4;`